# Calculate Timespan in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query a table that has dates in it. I would like to take the date from the table and compare it with the current time. I would like to see something like this.

```
2011.10.05 10:12:50 - Date time table
Current date
```

I need it to say `1 day 14 mins 13 secs`.

I thought about using `datesub()` in the query but it does not give me what I want. Is there a way to accomplish this in the query, if not I need to take another route. I even read through the manual but I could not find anything regarding timespan.

```
$query = "select country, rprice as regPrice, mprice as midPrice, pprice as prePrice, saddress as streetAddress,
                _id as ID, lat, lng, sname as Name, logo, admin_level_1 as state, locale as city, rdate as regDate, 
                mdate as midDate, pdate as preDate, 
                format((acos(sin(radians($lat1)) * sin(radians(lat)) + cos(radians($lat1)) *
                cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians($lng1) - radians(lng))) * 6378),1) as distance from stationDetails where 
                (acos(sin(radians($lat1)) * sin(radians(lat)) + cos(radians($lat1)) * cos(radians(lat)) * 
                cos(radians($lng1) - radians(lng))) * 6378) <= $rad order by $sort asc, $type asc";
```

This query works, but I need to take rdate, mdate, and pdate and convert it to time since it was updated in the database. @RolandoMySQLDBA query works well just like I wanted it but for some reason when I put it into the above query it breaks and tells me that I have in my SQL syntax.

EDIT: Here is what I came up with after tweaking a few things and learning how to write functions.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetTimeDisplay2` $$

CREATE FUNCTION `GetTimeDisplay2` (GivenTimestamp TIMESTAMP)

RETURNS VARCHAR(32)

DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN    

    DECLARE rv VARCHAR(32);

    DECLARE diff BIGINT;    

    SET diff = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(GivenTimestamp);

        IF diff < 0 THEN

        SET rv = CONCAT(abs(diff/60),' From Now');

    END IF;

    IF diff = 0 THEN

        SET rv = 'Just Now';

    END IF;

    IF diff = 1 THEN

        SET rv = '1 sec ago';

    END IF;

    IF diff BETWEEN 2 AND 60 THEN

        SET rv = CONCAT(FORMAT(diff, 0), ' secs ago');

    END IF;

    IF diff BETWEEN 120 AND 3599 THEN

        SET rv = CONCAT(FORMAT(diff/60, 0), ' mins ago');

    END IF;

    IF diff BETWEEN 61 AND 119 THEN

        SET rv = CONCAT(FORMAT(diff/60, 0), ' min ago');

    END IF;

    IF diff = 3600 THEN

        SET rv = CONCAT(FORMAT(diff/3600, 0), ' hr ago');

    END IF;

    IF diff BETWEEN 3601 AND 86399 THEN

        SET rv = CONCAT(FORMAT(diff/3600, 0), ' hrs ago');

    END IF;

    IF diff > 86400 THEN

        SET rv = DATE_FORMAT(GivenTimestamp, '%a %l:%i %p');

    END IF;

    IF diff > 259200 THEN

        SET rv = DATE_FORMAT(GivenTimestamp, '%b %e at %l:%i %p');

    END IF;

    RETURN rv;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. _How_ do you want to compare them, where does the `1 day 14 mins...` come from, and what doesn't `datesub()` give you?

Comment: You probably can use `TIMEDIFF()` and `DATE_FORMAT()`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will display the exact days, hours, minutes, and seconds from Feb 1, 2011 Midnight:

```
SELECT 
    TRIM(REPLACE(CONCAT(
        IF(dy=0,'',IF(dy=1,'1 day ',CONCAT(dy,' days '))),
        IF(hr=0,'',IF(hr=1,'1 hr ', CONCAT(hr,' hrs  '))),
        IF(mn=0,'',IF(mn=1,'1 min ',CONCAT(mn,' mins '))),
        IF(sc=0,'',IF(sc=1,'1 sec ',CONCAT(sc,' secs ')))),'  ',' '))
    TimeDisplay
FROM (SELECT dy,hr,mn,MOD(sec_aaaa,60) sc
FROM (SELECT dy,hr,FLOOR((sec_aaa - dy*86400 - hr*3600)/60) mn,sec_aaa sec_aaaa
FROM (SELECT dy,FLOOR((sec_aa - (dy*86400))/3600) hr,sec_aa sec_aaa
FROM (SELECT FLOOR(sec_a/86400) dy,sec_a sec_aa
FROM (SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-02-01 00:00:00')) sec_a)
A) AA) AAA) AAAA) B;
```

Just replace the `'2011-02-01 00:00:00'` with any datetime value or table column name you want.

Give it a Try !!!

**UPDATE 2011-10-06 13:38 EDT**

I wrote a stored function you can call that will handle this for you:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `test`.`GetTimeDisplay` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `test`.`GetTimeDisplay` (GivenTimestamp TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS VARCHAR(32)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE rv VARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE diff BIGINT;

    SET diff = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(GivenTimestamp);
    SELECT
        TRIM(REPLACE(CONCAT(
            IF(dy=0,'',IF(dy=1,'1 day ',CONCAT(dy,' days '))),
            IF(hr=0,'',IF(hr=1,'1 hr ', CONCAT(hr,' hrs  '))),
            IF(mn=0,'',IF(mn=1,'1 min ',CONCAT(mn,' mins '))),
            IF(sc=0,'',IF(sc=1,'1 sec ',CONCAT(sc,' secs ')))),'  ',' '))
    INTO rv
    FROM (SELECT dy,hr,mn,MOD(sec_aaaa,60) sc
    FROM (SELECT dy,hr,FLOOR((sec_aaa - dy*86400 - hr*3600)/60) mn,sec_aaa sec_aaaa
    FROM (SELECT dy,FLOOR((sec_aa - (dy*86400))/3600) hr,sec_aa sec_aaa
    FROM (SELECT FLOOR(sec_a/86400) dy,sec_a sec_aa
    FROM (SELECT ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(GivenTimestamp)) sec_a)
    A) AA) AAA) AAAA) B;

    IF diff = 0 THEN
        SET rv = '0 secs';
    END IF;
    IF diff < 0 THEN
        SET rv = CONCAT(rv,' From Now');
    END IF;
    IF diff > 0 THEN
        SET rv = CONCAT(rv,' Ago');
    END IF;

    RETURN rv;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

You can rewrite the query like this:

```
$query = "select country, rprice as regPrice, mprice as midPrice, pprice as prePrice, saddress as streetAddress,
                _id as ID, lat, lng, sname as Name, logo, admin_level_1 as state, locale as city, test.GetTimeDisplay(rdate) as regDate, 
                test.GetTimeDisplay(mdate) as midDate, test.GetTimeDisplay(pdate) as preDate, 
                format((acos(sin(radians($lat1)) * sin(radians(lat)) + cos(radians($lat1)) *
                cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians($lng1) - radians(lng))) * 6378),1) as distance from stationDetails where 
                (acos(sin(radians($lat1)) * sin(radians(lat)) + cos(radians($lat1)) * cos(radians(lat)) * 
                cos(radians($lng1) - radians(lng))) * 6378) <= $rad order by $sort asc, $type asc";
```

You may want to move the stored function to another database. The code I have puts the stored function in the test database.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Could you please take a look at the edits above? I am so lost on this right now. I am currently going over the MySQL manual with not much luck. I would love to use this in my query.

Comment: You can't just replace the `'2011-02-01 00:00:00'` with a table column, because the inner query apparently doesn't know about the outer table when I tried it: http://sqlize.com/re5H77qKr6

Comment: @mellamokb : You are right. It would be a little too messy (OK a Great Deal Too Messy) to integrate my query into Brandon's query. That's why I added a stored function to my answer.

Comment: @mellamokb : You left the extra semicolon in the middle of your query, just before from stationDetails.

Comment: Your the king, this resolved the issue. I wanted to keep this in the query for performance issues and keep PHP coding to the min. Thanks a lot guys for all your help. I am sure I will have more questions about queries. I see a lot of potential here.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: Whoops, you're right!  I have fixed it up and I still get the same message though.  What am I missing?  http://sqlize.com/yu8wH3LB1A

Comment: @mellamokb : Change `(SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(rdate)) sec_a)` to this `(SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(rdate)) sec_a FROM stationDetails)` and remove `from stationDetails` from the bottom.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: Cool, got it.  How would you return multiple rows then?  Would you have to match the id's with a WHERE statement?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: You did a great job with this function, however this is working just fine for me I would like to know how I can now have the timespan in a different format. For example if it is less than a minute have it display seconds (34 secs ago). If it is over a minute have it display just minutes (23 mins ago). If it is over a hour have it display just hours (1 hour ago). Finally if it is over 24 hours have it display the short date and time (Oct 4 at 2:45 pm). So something like SOF has setup.